# Has it become harder for Chinese students to be accepted into graduate programs in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, politics, china

There've been ominous news articles recently about the prospects of Chinese students (here meaning students from the People's Republic of China, as opposed to ethnic Chinese students from other countries such as Singapore) in the US, e.g.

- [Survey: US Public Opinion of China, Xi Drops Decisively](https://www.voanews.com/usa/survey-us-public-opinion-china-xi-drops-decisively)
- [US blocking visas of some Chinese graduate students and researchers: DHS](https://www.thedailystar.net/world/news/us-blocking-visas-some-chinese-graduate-students-and-researchers-dhs-1958769)
- [Chinese grad students at US universities may soon be expelled](https://www.mercurynews.com/2020/05/29/chinese-grad-students-may-be-next-hit-by-us-china-tensions-2/)

I am wondering how things are on the ground. I'm also interested in whether fewer Chinese students are applying to US graduate programs, if available. I know [some parents are worried](https://www.straitstimes.com/world/united-states/shutting-chinese-students-out-of-american-universities-hurts-the-us-more), but I don't know if that has translated into fewer applications.

**Edit: rephrased in concrete terms, are US universities now taking the applicant's country of origin into account in graduate admissions?**

Comment: Seeing as it has long been very difficult for Chinese students to get into top-ranked graduate programs in the US due to the high number of applicants from China, it's hard to see how "becoming harder" would make much difference to applicants.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I can't see the content of your objection. It's already hard for them, so it doesn't matter if it becomes much harder? Is that supposed to be a real argument?

Comment: @knzhou I was referring to applicant strategy, not outcomes.  When making a decision to try something, a 1% chance of success and a 0.1% chance of success are not meaningfully different.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I see that you've never had to try for a 1% chance in your life!

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, and (in response to now-deleted comments) I'm sure there is no intention of sparking a political debate. I am struggling a bit with whether this is answerable -- "whether it's less worthwhile" is probably a matter of opinion, and "how things are on the ground" will vary widely. On the other hand, a US-based professor involved with admissions (for example) might be able to share some relevant observations. The last part is answerable for sure, though it's probably too early for statistics to be available.

Comment: The question makes less sense now; I'm not aware of any admissions process that ever did not consider country of origin.  Though I might have heard German universities don't?

Comment: Funding may further shift towards classified/national interest projects, looking at my own university the extremely high number of non US citizens in graduate school has pretty much prevented professors from doing classified work. Many of the professors themselves can't pass security clearance because many are foreign. The US government is at a massive shortage of americans and I wouldn't be surprised depending upon 2020 outcome if restrictions are greatly tightened to force more US citizens to be selected. I don't think the issue is china really but noncitizen.

Answer (score 2):

US universities have always taken country of origin into account during admissions. I don't think there will be a major difference on the University side for admissions moving forward.

The visa situation is something else though. DHS is sitting on J1s, won't process H1Bs at all, but is still approving F1s and OPTs. This is likely to have a substantial chilling effect as it makes it much harder to do post completion training in the US.

I'm not sure they're going after china more than any other country - had a Singapore national just say forget it and walk away from a job offer over visa issues.