# Will Chinese students applying for PhD in the U.S. be affected by the relationship between China and the U.S.?

Tags: phd, application, united-states, china

I am Chinese, and I plan to apply for the 2022 Fall PhD in the U.S. I am confident with my research caliber and experience. However, I am worried about whether the terrible relationship between the U.S. and China will affect my application and other Chinese students, especially those in engineering and science majors.

I am not a CCP member, neither my spouse is (we don’t favor them at all), and I don’t have any relation to military-linked universities [1]. But I did have a working experience in a company that falls into the U.S. Commerce Department’s Entity List (not Huawei) [2]. Currently, I am working in a U.S. company.

I know many people sharing similar concerns with me, and your opinion could matter a lot to us. Thanks for your help.

---

[1] https://www.voanews.com/usa/us-ban-chinese-students-military-links-divides-experts-impact

[2] https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2019/10/09/2019-22210/addition-of-certain-entities-to-the-entity-list

Comment: Duplicate, although the linked question doesn't have a good answer either: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/155084/has-it-become-harder-for-chinese-students-to-be-accepted-into-graduate-programs

Comment: That is a good reference. Thanks @Allure. This question indeed could be unanswerable. Let's see what might have changed a year later from that question.

Comment: @gnometorule Thanks for your help. The non-security-sensitive looks like a vague term which can be interpreted differently in various contexts, which is exactly the thing troubles me. But I will still be giving my best effort and hope.

Comment: You need a visa. If you can get that, then you are just like any other international student. I doubt that any program would discriminate, though some individuals might. So, ask elsewhere if you are eligible for a visa to study.

Comment: Relevant with regards to the visa situation: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/373/6555/608

Comment: Australia government apparently misconstrue the 'military' exercise undertaken by all Chinese students at their university as being linked to the military.  A number of students' visa was cancelled for that reason.  Then again, they may just use that as a convenient reason.

Comment: So I would distinguish between this affecting your application and your enrollment: in general application/offers are handled by universities. The enrollment depends on visas, which are a government decision.

Comment: In addition to the issue of obtaining visa, you may find that you're ineligible to work on certain funded research projects because of your nationality.  This is particularly an issue with research projects funded by the Department of Energy and the Department of Defense.

Answer (score -4):

Tensions between China and America are having a profound effect on Chinese students in America. Chinese students' conduct is scrutinized very carefully these days. In addition, it would not surprise me one bit if their calls and email messages were being monitored very carefully. In addition, Chinese students - and especially those in science and technology fields - are being regarded with increasing suspicion by many people in the United States. To be honest, I think all of this is understandable when you think of all the Chinese citizens (residing in America) who have been arrested for espionage in recent years.